# How can I change JLabel text during work of JButton?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

I would like my button 'licz' to: change text value of info to ''loading'', do something and change 'info' to "done". ('licz' is here a JButton, 'info' JLabel)

```
        licz.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            info.setText("Loading..."); // Here
            if(go())
            {   
                brute(0);
                info.setText("Done!"); //here
                if(odwrot)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "good");
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "bad");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "bad");
                info.setText("Done"); // And here
            }

        }
    });
```

But the program makes "something" first, changes 'info' label to "loading" and immediately to "done", how to keep these in case?

Comment: What are `go()` and `brute(0);`? Does either take a lot of time, as in a long process to run?

Comment: These, buttons, action listeners etc. are in the same class. Program can sometimes work about 10 sec stucked and it looks like crashed when there is no "Loading" text

Comment: Aha :). Which line is taking a while? Presumably either `go()`(which returns boolean) or `brute(0)`.

Comment: I'm confused; what is your question? Are you wondering why there isn't a long wait in between? If so, that's because computers are pretty darn fast. You also shouldn't be doing any time consuming tasks on the Event Dispatch Thread. Use a `SwingWorker` if needed, and do the task in `doInBackground`. If you want to give the illusion of waiting, you could use `Thread.sleep`, but **do not call this in the EDT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event of actionPerformed is handled on the event handling thread, and should terminate fast to have a responsive GUI. Hence call `invokeLater`.

```
licz.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        info.setText("Loading...");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean good = false;
                if (go())
                {   
                    brute(0);
                    good = odwrot;
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, good ? "good" : "bad");
                info.setText("Done");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Or in java 8:

```
licz.addActionListener((e) -> {
    info.setText("Loading...");
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        boolean good = false;
        if (go())
        {   
            brute(0);
            good = odwrot;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, good ? "good" : "bad");
        info.setText("Done");
    });
});
```

Comment: He should actually be using a `SwingWorker` to handle the task *and* update his label. Also, although this is correct info, I'm not quite sure how this answers the question (although, I'm still trying to figure out what the question is)

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) has the purpose to do work really in the background, which is here not entirely the case. On the other hand for typical work less than five seconds, I would not start a first answer with an extra API layer. Maybe you want?

Comment: After taking another look, `brute` is still being called on the EDT. What you're doing is similar to what he's doing, other than maybe a smaller wait for it to execute (since you are posting it to the end of the queue). Yeah you have an extra API layer, but it gets the job done right, and that's what's important. You could always use a `Executors.singleThreadExecutor` and synchronize to avoid the layer, but no one wants to do that. I'm on my phone, not a fan of writing code from here, but if no one mentions it as the primary choice later, I'll probably create an answer

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes, the label will do "Loading..." and then the GUI freezes (a couple of seconds at most I hope), and a message pops up. I linked "SwingWorker" earlier to a tutorial.

Comment: The main problem with that is "gui freezes". You never want that, unless it was completely intentional. What if he wanted to make "Loading" gain dots one at a time, like a real loading screen? He would have to switch to `SwingWorker` anyways. What you have is a buggy fix, and is teaching him poor programming. The GUI should NEVER freeze, only give the illusion of freezing

Comment: @VinceEmigh I really think you have a point, I upvoted your remark and even asked for an answer, which I have never done before. As this seems a dedicated app, non-production, ("go()", "brute()" and even "odwrot") I do not see the need to prevent a freeze. Being lazy. Also invokeLater is the first thing to learn.

Comment: That's pretty funny, cause I was hoping I'd scare you into updating your answer. I'm feeling pretty lazy too. Hopefully someone stumbles across these comments..